# Django. Как срендерить переменную в html, который определён в другой функции?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

Дан views.py в котором две функции:

```
def get_names(channel_id):

    ...

    for rediska in following_list:
        if rediska not in followers_list:
            print('That rediska ' + 'unfollow' + ' you -> ' + rediska)


    for dude in followers_list:
        if dude not in following_list:
            print('That dude ' + 'needs your support -> ' + dude)




def index(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = Boom_Form(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            channel_id = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            get_names(channel_id)
            return render(request, 'Boom_App/index.html', {'form': form}, context={'rediska':rediska})

            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/about/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = Boom_Form()

    return render(request, 'Boom_App/index.html', {'form': form})
```

И есть index.html

```
    </header>

    {% block content %}
    {% for rediska in following_list %}
          {% if rediska not in followers_list %}
              <p>That rediska unfollow you -> {{rediska}}</p>
          {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% endblock content %}

    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="form-group">

        {{ form }}
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>



  </body>
</html>
```

Вопрос, почему мне выдаётся ошибка NameError, а именно

> name 'rediska' is not defined

если она (переменная rediska) указана как в html, так и во views.py, правда в отдельной функции.

Comment: Переменные должны быть внутри функции, которая передается в url

Answer (score 0):

А ещё в трейсбеке (который вы любезно предоставили) указана строка, на которой вывалилась ошибка.

Ошибка в функции `index` в строке:

```
return render(request, 'Boom_App/index.html', {'form': form}, context={'rediska':rediska})
```

Тут даже 2 ошибки:

1. Смотрите, какие аргументы и как передаются в функцию `render` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render
2. Переменная `rediska` не определена в этой функций. Это азы питона, учите их для начала.

По поводу вопроса - чтобы передать значение с одной функцию в другую возможны несколько вариантов:

1. global (нежелательно)
2. вызвать первую функцию, присвоить возвращаемое значение этой функции какой-то переменной - и ей оперировать.

Ну либо же определять это значение сразу внутри второй функции.

А ещё невидно, где вы с первой функции передаёте `following_list` в шаблон.

В общем, очень много ошибок - учите азы.